# Which celestial body's length of day is closest to that of Earth?

Tags: solar-system, rotation

I know the planets Mars and Eris are among bodies that have the most Earth-like mean solar days (about 24.67 and 25.9 hrs). Among moons there is Mimas of Saturn which has one of the most Earth-like days. Uranus and Neptune also have more Earth-like day lengths than many other known planets or moons. However I don't know of a body in the Earth's planetary system that would have a more Earth-like solar day than Mars (other than the Earth of course). Do you know a planet, moon or asteroid that has a daylength closer to that of Earth than Mars' is?

Comment: Have you tried using the [JPL Small-Body Database Search Engine](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb_query.cgi)? It allows for filtering on rotation period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Methone**, a tiny moon of Saturn has an orbital period of 1.01 days. This is approximately 24 hrs and 14 minutes. Ref. 1

1. https://www.windows2universe.org/our_solar_system/moons_table.html

Answer (score 2):

### Makemake

It is a dwarf planet in the Kuiper Belt that has a day that is close to Earth's. One day on Makemake is 22.48 hours. https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/dwarf-planets/makemake/in-depth/

Comment: That daylength is close to that of the moon Mimas. However it's farther than Mars' solar day. I'd like to know whether there's a known body whose day resembles the Earth's more than the Martian day of about 24.67 hrs (mean Solar day on Mars).

Comment: Hi @DeanPitts `+1` and Welcome to Stack Exchange! Can you cite a source or add a link or at least *explain* why you think this is 1) true and 2) the answer to the question? (i.e. " closest to that of Earth") Thanks!

Comment: https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/dwarf-planets/makemake/in-depth/